# Excel formatting rows

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aord1.png)I want to format the data in a row. My data right now is 012378 numbers in all rows, but I want to convert the whole row as ('012378').  There are total 9000 rows

I tried formatting the rows and selecting them but nothing comes up for this particular formatting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aord1.png)

Comment: I don't understand how your data looks currently; you say "012378 numbers in all rows". What does that mean? What does it mean to "Convert the whole role as ("012378")"? How does a row convert to a number? Can you share some sample data and desired results?

Comment: @ JNevill sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CONCAT formula.

Cell B1 formula:

```
=CONCAT("('",A1,"')")
```

Drag it down, done.

[image]

Comment: A similar option: `="('" & A1 & "')"`.